# Targetting element:only-child with no sibling text node

Tags: css

I have content coming from a WYSIWYG editor in use by a technologically uninitiated client, with a pretty challenging request to go with it.

Basically, any time an `<a>` is alone inside a `<p>`, they want that `<a>` to be styled like a button. When I say "alone inside a `<p>`", I am also meaning that there is literally no surrounding text.

For example's sake:

```
<p><a href="/foo">Bar</a></p>
```

Is styled like a button, whereas

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="/foo">Bar</a></p>
```

Is not.

Unfortunately the `:only-child` pseudo class does not suffice here, as it doesn't consider the text node to be an element, and so both examples above would be styled as buttons.

I believe the answer is no, but is there any pure CSS solution to this?

Comment: Not that I know of: you will probably have to use JS for this.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30463098/8375199) might be relevant.

Comment: Accepted as duplicate. Thanks everyone.